# Correct way to store encryption key for SqlCipher database

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlcipher

I have a Xamarin application and have managed to download my data from my server to my device. I have also got it set up so that it can take a SqlCipher Encryption key to encrypt the data.

My question is where is the correct location to store my key that I use to encrypt this data? Is it to you KeyStore / KeyChain? Which mono classes should I be looking to use?

Comment: As far as I know your best options are Keychain for iOS and KeyStore for Android. [Mono example for Keychain](https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/Keychain)

Comment: And also a [Mono example for KeyStore](https://github.com/escfrya/Locator/blob/3297318c781aabc67b6d303cddaa792af2dcf6c4/Xamarin.Auth/Xamarin.Auth.Android/AndroidAccountStore.cs)

Comment: @Wizche I have looked at the android mono example and it seems to be using the nuget Xamarin.Auth. Because I can't reference Xamarin.Auth in my PCL this means I can't use the methods from my PCL via an interface using dependency injection. I would therefore say this is not a good way to store encryption keys using Xamarin

Comment: As far as I know Xamarin.Auth is using Keystore and keychain for storing auth tokens, you will need a custom implementation for your goal and the code above should give you some hints on how to use such native APIs in mono.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the popularity of this question I am going to post my implementation of this:

**PCL interface**

```
public interface IAuth
{
    void CreateStore();
    IEnumerable<string> FindAccountsForService(string serviceId);
    void Save(string pin,string serviceId);
    void Delete(string serviceId);
}
```

**Android**

```
public class IAuthImplementation : IAuth
{
    Context context;
    KeyStore ks;
    KeyStore.PasswordProtection prot;

    static readonly object fileLock = new object();

    const string FileName = "MyProg.Accounts";
    static readonly char[] Password = null;

    public void CreateStore()
    {

        this.context = Android.App.Application.Context;

        ks = KeyStore.GetInstance(KeyStore.DefaultType);

        prot = new KeyStore.PasswordProtection(Password);

        try
        {
            lock (fileLock)
            {
                using (var s = context.OpenFileInput(FileName))
                {
                    ks.Load(s, Password);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Java.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            //ks.Load (null, Password);
            LoadEmptyKeyStore(Password);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> FindAccountsForService(string serviceId)
    {
        var r = new List<string>();

        var postfix = "-" + serviceId;

        var aliases = ks.Aliases();
        while (aliases.HasMoreElements)
        {
            var alias = aliases.NextElement().ToString();
            if (alias.EndsWith(postfix))
            {
                var e = ks.GetEntry(alias, prot) as KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry;
                if (e != null)
                {
                    var bytes = e.SecretKey.GetEncoded();
                    var password = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
                    r.Add(password);
                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public void Delete(string serviceId)
    {
        var alias = MakeAlias(serviceId);

        ks.DeleteEntry(alias);
        Save();
    }

    public void Save(string pin, string serviceId)
    {
        var alias = MakeAlias(serviceId);

        var secretKey = new SecretAccount(pin);
        var entry = new KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry(secretKey);
        ks.SetEntry(alias, entry, prot);

        Save();
    }

    void Save()
    {
        lock (fileLock)
        {
            using (var s = context.OpenFileOutput(FileName, FileCreationMode.Private))
            {
                ks.Store(s, Password);
            }
        }
    }

    static string MakeAlias(string serviceId)
    {
        return "-" + serviceId;
    }

    class SecretAccount : Java.Lang.Object, ISecretKey
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        public SecretAccount(string password)
        {
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
        }
        public byte[] GetEncoded()
        {
            return bytes;
        }
        public string Algorithm
        {
            get
            {
                return "RAW";
            }
        }
        public string Format
        {
            get
            {
                return "RAW";
            }
        }
    }

    static IntPtr id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC;

    void LoadEmptyKeyStore(char[] password)
    {
        if (id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC = JNIEnv.GetMethodID(ks.Class.Handle, "load", "(Ljava/io/InputStream;[C)V");
        }
        IntPtr intPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr intPtr2 = JNIEnv.NewArray(password);
        JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod(ks.Handle, id_load_Ljava_io_InputStream_arrayC, new JValue[]
            {
                new JValue (intPtr),
                new JValue (intPtr2)
            });
        JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(intPtr);
        if (password != null)
        {
            JNIEnv.CopyArray(intPtr2, password);
            JNIEnv.DeleteLocalRef(intPtr2);
        }
    }
```

Call Create Store in the main activity of Android app first. - This could possibly be improved and remove CreateStrore() from the interface by checking if ks == null in Save and Delete and calling the method if true

**iOS**

```
public class IAuthImplementation : IAuth
{
    public IEnumerable<string> FindAccountsForService(string serviceId)
    {
        var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
        query.Service = serviceId;

        SecStatusCode result;
        var records = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(query, 1000, out result);

        return records != null ?
            records.Select(GetAccountFromRecord).ToList() :
            new List<string>();
    }

    public void Save(string pin, string serviceId)
    {
        var statusCode = SecStatusCode.Success;
        var serializedAccount = pin;
        var data = NSData.FromString(serializedAccount, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);

        //
        // Remove any existing record
        //
        var existing = FindAccount(serviceId);

        if (existing != null)
        {
            var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
            query.Service = serviceId;

            statusCode = SecKeyChain.Remove(query);
            if (statusCode != SecStatusCode.Success)
            {
                throw new Exception("Could not save account to KeyChain: " + statusCode);
            }
        }

        //
        // Add this record
        //
        var record = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
        record.Service = serviceId;
        record.Generic = data;
        record.Accessible = SecAccessible.WhenUnlocked;

        statusCode = SecKeyChain.Add(record);

        if (statusCode != SecStatusCode.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not save account to KeyChain: " + statusCode);
        }
    }

    public void Delete(string serviceId)
    {
        var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
        query.Service = serviceId;

        var statusCode = SecKeyChain.Remove(query);

        if (statusCode != SecStatusCode.Success)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not delete account from KeyChain: " + statusCode);
        }
    }

    string GetAccountFromRecord(SecRecord r)
    {
        return NSString.FromData(r.Generic, NSStringEncoding.UTF8);
    }

    string FindAccount(string serviceId)
    {
        var query = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword);
        query.Service = serviceId;

        SecStatusCode result;
        var record = SecKeyChain.QueryAsRecord(query, out result);

        return record != null ? GetAccountFromRecord(record) : null;
    }

    public void CreateStore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**WP**

```
public class IAuthImplementation : IAuth
{
    public IEnumerable<string> FindAccountsForService(string serviceId)
    {
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            string[] auths = store.GetFileNames("MyProg");
            foreach (string path in auths)
            {
                using (var stream = new BinaryReader(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, store)))
                {
                    int length = stream.ReadInt32();
                    byte[] data = stream.ReadBytes(length);

                    byte[] unprot = ProtectedData.Unprotect(data, null);
                    yield return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(unprot, 0, unprot.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Save(string pin, string serviceId)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pin);
        byte[] prot = ProtectedData.Protect(data, null);

        var path = GetAccountPath(serviceId);

        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        using (var stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, store))
        {
            stream.WriteAsync(BitConverter.GetBytes(prot.Length), 0, sizeof(int)).Wait();
            stream.WriteAsync(prot, 0, prot.Length).Wait();
        }
    }

    public void Delete(string serviceId)
    {
        var path = GetAccountPath(serviceId);
        using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            store.DeleteFile(path);
        }
    }

    private string GetAccountPath(string serviceId)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}", serviceId);
    }

    public void CreateStore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is an adaptation of the Xamarin.Auth library ([Found Here](https://github.com/escfrya/Locator/blob/3297318c781aabc67b6d303cddaa792af2dcf6c4/Xamarin.Auth/Xamarin.Auth.Android/AndroidAccountStore.cs)) but removes the dependency from the Xamarin.Auth library to provide cross platform use through the interface in the PCL. For this reason I have simplified it to only save one string. This is probably not the best implementation but it works in my case. Feel free to expand upon this

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, just out of interest how do you handle the pin?  Is this a user entered value?  Where do you store that value?  Thanks again.

Comment: @Jammer yes the pin is a user entered value. This code stores the value in the `KeyStore` on Android, `KeyChain` on iOS and `IsolatedStorage` on WP, they are all basically the same thing and all 3 are encrypted making it secure

Comment: I understood that bit.  I'm building something similar at the moment.  My question was really about whether you then store this pin or prompt for it any time it's needed?

Comment: @Jammer In my case ask the user to create a pin initially and store it. Then on application start up I prompt the user for the pin and compare it the the stored version to unlock my application

Comment: Gotcha, that does seem to be a common approach.  Thanks for your time chap.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. How do you handle when someone tries to unlock an existing Keystore with the wrong password?

Answer (score 2):

There is a nuget package called [KeyChain.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/KeyChain.Net/) that encapsulated this logic for iOs, Android and Windows Phone.

It's open source and you have find sample at its [github repository](https://github.com/has-taiar/KeyChain.Net)

More info at this [blog post](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2015/05/06/announcing-keychain-net-a-unified-api-for-using-keychain-on-many-platforms/)